What is the meaning of the "Super 8 - Interactive Teaser" under "EXTRAS" in Portal 2?
I just played through the following "Super 8 - Interactive Teaser" in Portal 2:

Whilst it was pretty cool, what the hell is it? What does it mean?

Super 8 was a 2011 sci-fi movie directed by JJ Abrams. What you played through was exactly what it says on the tin: an interactive teaser for that movie. In the movie, a train derails when it collides with a truck, and a captive alien is able to escape the wreckage. The Portal 2 map is just a recreation of that scene for the purpose of advertising/hyping the movie prior to its release.

That's a bit of a weird thing to put into Portal 2

JJ Arbrams put a teaser of the episode IX of the Star Wars in Fortnite.

Shhh, stop reminding us that it has been 13 years since this game came out.

@user28434 Not even a teaser; he put a key plot point that is otherwise very briefly mentioned in the Text Crawl, but that characters on both sides are reacting to from the moment the film starts.

The Super 8 - Interactive Teaser was a promotional tie in for the 2011 movie Super 8. A train derails during the movie, which is recreated in the interactive teaser.
The director for Super 8, J.J. Abrams, was known to be a fan of Half-Life and Portal. A bit after the release of Portal 2 in 2013, there were talks of Abrams directing a Half-Life or Portal movie.
